# Exclude a path from a Meteor application

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to run a Meteor application from the root path, but have another application (like a webshop or Wordpress) running in a subpath like `/store`?

I know I can put stuff in the `/public` directory, but Modulus can't run PHP for instance so that won't work..

Comment: Are you trying to run that on Public server or locally?

Comment: This article might be helpful  
[Add wordpress to your meteor js site][1]


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139131/add-wordpress-to-meteor-js-site

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. It would be on a public server I guess. A client wants to update her PHP application to Meteor, but wants to keep using her existing store and blog.

Comment: Alternatively I can suggest we put the Meteor application in a subpath like `/app` and forward that to Modulus with an .htaccess or something.